# How to put content inside android with navigation drawer template

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Im' new to android development, I'm creating new project android with template that having navigation drawer. it show the if - else state on selected menu item on drawer. and the content part suppose to be on main_content.xml.

My question is: how to change content of the main content part when i select different menu? if i load another intent, it will have different design, unless i copy the layout all over again, but it would be repetitive and hard to maintain.

Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: If you want to change color and theme, then it is better to just change using style of drawer. Or if you want change only some menu, then `HIDE` or `VISIBLE` that menu-submenu in drawer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fragment to change the content of you layout

Just create a Fragment Subclass extending from Fragment class
You can read more about it in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

After that .update the onNavigationMenuSelected method by checking the appropriate case in the switch case statement and updating it with code as below

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack

transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load different different content and screen inside of same navigation drawer screen then you need to understand concept of fragment, And then you can manage different different screen in single activity.

Here is the link for full documentation for fragment, Also after understand fragment you can manage or load fragment throw menu.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html